# multiple sql queries into one small and better query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using these queries in my php page and I think there is a better way to do the same thing.

```
$cms1 = getRow("select * from cms where cmsID=1");
$cms2 = getRow("select * from cms where cmsID=2");
$cms3 = getRow("select * from cms where cmsID=3");
$cms4 = getRow("select * from cms where cmsID=4");
$cms5 = getRow("select * from cms where cmsID=5");
```

I am printing the data from these queries like

```
<?=$cms['content']?> 
<?=$cms2['content']?>
<?=$cms3['content']?> ....
```

Is there a better way to do this or to get all this data in one single query? I think I might get the result by using `AS` key in the query but I have no idea how.

```
function getRow($query)
{
    $rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($rs))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);      
        return $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `IN`

```
select * from cms where cmsID in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

> You can use IN clause to replace many OR conditions

```
$sql = "select * from cms where cmsID in (1,2,3,4,5)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['cmsID'].' '.$row['content'];//output like  :- 1 content
    }
```

Comment: and then how to print the data ??

Comment: buddy content is different when we select different cmsID

Answer (score 0):

This can also be best achieved using

> BETWEEN

in mysql

```
 SELECT * FROM cms WHERE cmsID BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

For more information on Between clause, you can visit this [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm)

```
$arrData = array();
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

    array_push($arrData,$row);
}

print_r($arrData);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All change your function

```
function getRow($query)
{

$rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$result = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($rs))
 {

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
   {
       $record[$row['cmsID']] = $row;
   }

 return $record;
 }
}
```

Then change your query

```
$output = getRow(select * from cms where cmsID in (1,2,3,4,5));
```

Then echo your output.

```
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

for($i=1;$i<=5; $i++) {
$cms1 = getRow("select * from cms where cmsID='".$i."'");

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.